# Oracle - Service Account vs Database Account?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I'm a developer and not a DBA, specifically not an Oracle DBA. I have a Java application that is connecting to a Oracle 11g R2 database. I have an account and schema called "OBR". I am being told the Java application cannot use the "OBR" user account to access Oracle. Policy, best practices, not sure why but it is what I have to do.

Anyway I've been doing some searching and not sure what the difference is between a service account and standard database account for Oracle. Which one do I want to use?

Right now I'm thinking just create a new database user leave the schema empty and give them access to the OBR schema to execute packages.

Answer (score 1):

Not that unusual for a best practice if done well.  I see read only service accounts and more powerful accounts for web services to connect with

- create a user and give the user a complex password
- do not ever create any objects in this schema
- create a role with connect privilege and which has the appropriate grants on the OBR schema
- grant the role to the user
- limit the amount of table space of the user
- make their role the default role

Once you have done this you have a more secure setup for access.